# Sphinx and Markdown: hyperlinks to section in a different file

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx

I'm trying to convert Markdown files to html using Sphinx and I am having trouble with links that point to a section in a different Markdown file.

**Original Markdown (reference to section):**

```
[Kubernetes installation](15-kubernetes.md#installation)
```

**Generated html with Sphinx (WRONG):**

```
<p><a class="reference external" href="15-kubernetes.md#installation">Kubernetes installation</a></p>
```

As you can see, the reference keeps the .md extension and does not replace it by the expected .html extension.

However, when pointing directly to a file, not to a specific section, the conversion works well and the .md extension is properly replaced by .html extension:

**Original Markdown (reference to file):**

```
[Kubernetes installation](15-kubernetes.md)
```

**Generated html with Sphinx (RIGHT):**

```
<p><a class="reference external" href="15-kubernetes.html">Kubernetes installation</a></p>
```

Any idea on how to make it work for sections in a different file?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark#linking-to-headings-in-other-files